# How to only find earliest date only

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need my output to look like this

```
job_id      po_id       po_date     vendor_id
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
005         FFF         1989-12-01  ABC
004         CCC         1990-01-05  SOS
006         GGG         1988-07-15  XYZ
```

When I am currently getting this

```
job_id      po_id       po_date     vendor_id
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
002         AAA         1990-05-20  ABC
004         DDD         1990-01-01  ABC
005         FFF         1989-12-01  ABC
004         CCC         1990-01-05  SOS
005         EEE         1990-01-15  SOS
002         BBB         1990-03-15  XYZ
006         GGG         1988-07-15  XYZ
```

I would like my code to show only the earliest dates of each vendor_id

any help would be appreciated and I have to do this on SQL lite and I can not use group by, this is my current code

```
select job_id, po_id, po_date, vendor_id
from pos
where po_date >=
  (Select min(po_date)
  from pos )
  order by vendor_id;
```

Comment: This works: `select job_id,po_id,min(po_date) po_date,vendor_id from t group by vendor_id`.  I don't know why you say you can't use `group by`.  Unlike other database engines, SQLite3 will give you the matching same row columns for `min()` or `max()` functions over a `group by` (this is documented behavior), assuming you use just one of them to keep it unambiguous.  So, two `min()` or a `min()` and a `max()` will not work.  But, for your example, it works.

Answer (score 0):

With this query:

```
select vendor_id, min(po_date) po_date
from pos
group by vendor_id
```

you get the earliest `po_date` for each `vendor_id` and then you must join it to the table:

```
select p.job_id, p.po_id, p.po_date, p.vendor_id
from pos p inner join (
  select vendor_id, min(po_date) po_date
  from pos
  group by vendor_id
) g on g.vendor_id = p.vendor_id and g.po_date = p.po_date
order by p.vendor_id
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without join?

Comment: If you mean something like your code with only a WHERE clause I don't think so. Even if it was possible it would be less efficient. You need to get the min date for each vendor. This means you need 2 values to compare against each row of the table.

Comment: I know its less efficient but Is it possible for you to show me how?

Comment: I said *I don't think so* only because maybe there is a way, but I can't think of any.

Comment: Only because i need it to be set out the way that I have

Comment: If it helps this is the question i need to answer  Find the earliest po_date for each vendor_id in the pos table, include all the columns from the pos table and order by vendor_id. This cannot be done by a GROUP BY. You will need to use a correlated query based on the vendor_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Sqlite 3.25 or newer, it's easy to do with window functions:

```
SELECT job_id, po_id, po_date, vendor_id
FROM (SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY vendor_id ORDER BY po_date) AS rn FROM pos)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY vendor_id;
```

Basically, this partitions all the rows in the table by `vendor_id` (Very similar in concept to GROUP BY, except it's applied to all the result rows, not when generating result rows), and sorts each partition by `po_date`, and then numbers them according to their ranking - all the purchase orders on the earliest date for each vendor will have rank 1. Then the outer query only selects those rank 1 rows.

For best results, have an index on `pos(vendor_id, po_date)`.

---

Non-window function approach that doesn't use `GROUP BY` or `JOIN` per OP's requirements. This one **really** needs that aforementioned index to minimize full table scans.

```
SELECT job_id, po_id, po_date, vendor_id
FROM pos AS p1
WHERE po_date = (SELECT min(p2.po_date) FROM pos AS p2 WHERE p1.vendor_id = p2.vendor_id)
ORDER BY vendor_id;
```

Compare this to the one in your question; you were pretty much just missing limiting the subquery to the current row's `vendor_id` and the right date comparison.

Comment: I must be on an older version because it does not work and I need to set it out like i have

Comment: @Tarkoman09 If you're stuck on an old version of sqlite that doesn't support window functions, this answer won't work, no.

Comment: @Tarkoman09 See the other answer for one reasonably efficient way.

Comment: @Tarkoman09 See edit to my answer for a not very efficient way.

Comment: Yep thank you so much that is what i was looking for